# How to get the values from tags based on position dynamically in Xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes

I think I have stuck in sever issue where I am parsing the XML using Xpath...while parsing the XML I may have multiple repeated tags but with different data lets take an example....

```
<note>
<to>Tove 1</to>
<from>Jani 1</from>
<heading>Reminder 1</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend One!</body>
</note>
<!-Second Node -!>
<note>
<to>Tove 2</to>
<from>Jani 2</from>
<heading>Reminder 2</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend Second!</body>
</note>
```

> //note/to/text() to get text from `<to>` tag --> My Xpath

But the issue is I don't know how many tags may be there, in the above Xpath I get the first not value everytime...

NOTE: I know I can use [1],[2] if I know the number of tags but how to do dynamically

Comment: which one do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `//` for relative xpath as below :-

```
//note//to/text()
```

Refer:-

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_relative_path.htm

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the elements quantity:

`count(//note//to/text())`

If you want to get a cell based on a text:

`//note//to/[text() = 'Jani 1']/text()`